# Swing Form not displaying correctly

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to generate a UDP server here with a basic GUI. The issue I am having is when I move my `Datagram` socket from the main method to its own method so I can output to a `jTextArea` my GUI stop displaying. I believe it has something to do with the `setVisible(true)` but no what I do I can't seem to get it displaying correctly any help would be appreciated

```
package Assignment1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class UDPServer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public UDPServer() throws IOException {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
        FileRead();
        runServer();
    }


    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        ClearLog = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ClearLog.setText("Clear Log");
        ClearLog.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ClearLogActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        TextArea.setColumns(20);
        TextArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(TextArea);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(ClearLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(ClearLog)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 271, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void ClearLogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        TextArea.setText("");
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
      /*  try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UDPServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UDPServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UDPServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UDPServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new UDPServer().setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(UDPServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }


            }
        }

        );   
    }



    public void FileRead() throws IOException {

        String file_name = "C:/Users/Ross/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Assignment1/src/Assignment1/Data.txt";

        try {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

            int i;
            for (i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage());
        }
    }

     public void runServer(){

         try(DatagramSocket aSocket = new DatagramSocket(8789)) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

                DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

                        while(true)
                            {
                aSocket.receive(request);
                TextArea.setText("Client Request: " + new String(request.getData(), 0, request.getLength()));
                                DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(request.getData(), request.getLength(), 
                    request.getAddress(), request.getPort());
                                aSocket.send(reply);
                            }
        }catch (SocketException e){System.out.println("Socket: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
     }

      public void SetText(){

        TextArea.setText("Hello");
        TextArea.append("This is a test"); 

     }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton ClearLog;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea TextArea;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind this is a work in progress which much more to go hense the random bits of code like the ReadFile() and setText() as they will eventually have use but not until i get this GUI displaying again and the socket listening

Comment: How does the GUI stop displaying ? Do you get any error/ stacktrace ?

Comment: Don't make an infinite loop in Event Dispatcher Thread. This makes UI unresponsible. Please read topic about the [concurrency in swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). So you can understand what's wrong how you can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are calling the `runServer` method on the [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). If the `runServer` method blocks, then your user interface will not get updated.

One quick solution would be to update your constructor as follows, so that the `runServer` runs in its own thread.

```
public UDPServer() throws IOException {
    initComponents();
    setVisible(true);
    FileRead();
    new Thread(()->runServer()).start();
}
```

But you should do any UI updates in the EDT. For example the `TextArea.setTex` should be done in the EDT. You can check how it can be done in the documentation linked above.

Comment: @Rossco88 but please read the documentation. Even though this fixes the problem, you should change the contents of the `runServer` method so that any UI updates happens in the EDT. Maybe https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html will help